# how print all subarray of giving array (short type soltuion on javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

**I wanna solutions of this problem plc help**

```js
var s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i; j < s.length; j++) {
    str = "";
    for (var k = i; k <= j; k++) {
      str += s[k];
    }

    console.log(str);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want contiguous subarrays? Because that's what it seems from your code. Also you are not returning an array of subarrays, you are returning an array of strings made from subarrays.

Here I modified your code to output all the contiguous subarrays of an array:

```
function printSubArray() {
  var s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  let res = [[]]
  for (let len = 1 ; len <= s.length; len++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < s.length - len + 1; j++) {
      let temp = []
      for (var k = j; k < j + len; k++) {
        temp.push(s[k])
      }
      res.push(temp)
    }
  }
  return res
}

console.log(printSubArray())
```